# Reloading content into a div at certain interval with jQuery and tabs

Tags: jquery, load, queue, click, setinterval

I had a few tabs that, when clicked, use jquery to load data into a div. I need the data to reload at a 5 second interval, but only the info from the particular tab. So, here's what I have... I think I need to start a setInterval when a tab is clicked, then stop it when another is clicked. Here's my code for the tabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#xicon1").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
     });
  $("#xicon2").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $("#actionlist").load("alpending.php");
     });
  $("#xicon3").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $("#actionlist").load("alpast.php");
     });
});
</script>
```

So for example, when #xicon1 is clicked, I need it to load alcurrent.php into #actionlist (I can do this), but I need it to reload it every 5 seconds. Then when I click another tab, I need that one to start loading every 5 seconds. So, whichever tab is active, I need the content loaded every 5 seconds.

I've tried setInterval... but no dice.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's what I've done and I think it works...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#xicon1").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon1() {
     $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
     }
     setInterval(xicon1, 5000);
     });
  $("#xicon2").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon2() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>2</p>")
     }
     setInterval(xicon2, 5000);
     });
  $("#xicon3").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon3() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>3</p>")
     }
     setInterval(xicon3, 5000);
     });
});
</script>
```

Edit2: this might be a little prettier:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#xicon1").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon1() {
     $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
     };
     $(function() {
     setInterval(xicon1, 5000);
     };
  });
  $("#xicon2").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon2() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>2</p>")
     };
     setInterval(xicon2, 5000);
  });
  $("#xicon3").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     function xicon3() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>3</p>")
     };
     setInterval(xicon3, 5000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Okay, I just want to be sure: When someone clicks on a different tab, its going to stop the other tab's content from refreshing every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the syntax of your setInterval, have you tried it like this?

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Do i put that somehow like this?     
    $("#xicon3").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $("#actionlist").load("alpast.php");
     setInterval(function ()...................
     });

Comment: You can use Firebugs net panel to find out if it works, it will display a new request every 5 minutes (or you could display the time on the page that you are requesting)

Comment: The problem is it keeps refreshing the content from alcurrent.php each 5 seconds. I need it to stop that interval

Comment: And also, each time I click it, it adds another iteration to the interval. (i.e. if I click it twice, it reloads it twice per 5 seconds.)

Comment: Any ideas on maybe running a function every 5 seconds that detects which tab is set to class="active" and then loading a particular page.... I only have 3 tabs so I don't think it'd be too difficult...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to clear the interval when a new tab is clicked and reset it, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var the_interval = 0;

  $("#xicon1").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");

     if (the_interval) {
        clearInterval(the_interval);
     }
     xicon1();  // I would call it here, to load newest data as soon as tab is clicked

     function xicon1() {
     $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
     };
     $(function() {
     the_interval = setInterval(xicon1, 5000);
     };
  });
  $("#xicon2").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");

     if (the_interval) {
        clearInterval(the_interval);
     }
     xicon2();  // I would call it here, to load newest data as soon as tab is clicked

     function xicon2() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>2</p>")
     };
     setInterval(xicon2, 5000);
  });
  $("#xicon3").click(function(){
     $('a[name^="xicon"]').removeClass();
     $(this).addClass("active");

     if (the_interval) {
        clearInterval(the_interval);
     }
     xicon3();  // I would call it here, to load newest data as soon as tab is clicked

     function xicon3() {
     $("#actionlist").html("<p>3</p>")
     };
     setInterval(xicon3, 5000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I ended up doing this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013940/jquery-load-something-based-on-whose-class-is-active/5013982#5013982)[/link]. But thanks for your response!