# jQuery load something based on whose class is "active"

Tags: jquery, load, setinterval

I'm trying to use this with tabs that load content with ajax into a div. I can't get it to refresh on the interval. The top part does work, however.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function rlAl() {
    if ($("#xicon1").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
    }
    else if ($("#xicon2").hasClass("active")) {
    alert("icon2");
    }
    else if ($("#xicon3").hasClass("active")) {
    alert("icon3");
    }
 });
 $(function() {
 setInterval(rlAl, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Btw, it it probably a better idea to load (and cache) the content every time the tab changes, and not every 5 seconds. Every 5 seconds can be heavy on the server (assuming many concurrent users). So if I just sit on the page and do nothing for 5 minutes (maybe I went for a break and left the site open), the script will connect to the server 60 times. Imagine 500 users - that's 30,000 useless connections every 5 minutes. That's not too much to handle, but it is definitely wasted server resources. Maybe try preloading the content if you can, or caching it, or loading when they change tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rlAl is undefined` because it wasn't attached to the global scope, take it out of the `$()` you have it in in order to register it in the `window` namespace

```
function rlAl() {
  if ($("#xicon1").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#actionlist").load("alcurrent.php");
  }
  else if ($("#xicon2").hasClass("active")) {
    alert("icon2");
  }
  else if ($("#xicon3").hasClass("active")) {
    alert("icon3");
  }
}
$(function() {
  rlAl(); // so it executes straight away on DOM ready
  setInterval(rlAl, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. How come the second function is within $( then?

Comment: @Andy, `$()` executes the function passed to it when the dom is ready (i.e. all your html is ready for maipulation. see http://api.jquery.com/ready/), so first you need to define the function (which is the first thing in the above code) and then when the dom is ready you can start executing it every few seconds. Analogy, first you have to wait for the shop to open, only then you can bug the owner every 5 seconds. So first you prepare your bugging speech (i.e. define the function), and then wait for the shop to open (dom to be ready) and then you can begin hassling (setInterval)

Comment: @Davin, Haha thanks for explaining! Don't mean to keep going on, but I'm just trying to learn... When my page loads, it loads the first part of the first function. #xicon1 is set by default to class="active" and I can tell this is loading because it loads it right as the page loads, not 5 seconds later. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: @Andy, not too sure what your question is. Try remove the line `rlAl();` and you'll see that it waits 5 seconds to load for the first time. When you define a function it *doesn't* execute it, it just loads the code. So only in the `$()` block do we execute it for the first time. After that, it happens every 5 seconds. Although again you can test this - try removing the entire `$()` block, and you'll see even though the entire first function is there, it will never load anything